# How to trigger a local Jenkins build from a remote Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a local Jenkins build that I need to trigger based on watching a remote Jenkins job.  This is the inverse of the [Parameterized Remote Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Remote+Trigger+Plugin).  The remote Jenkins instance is not under my control.  I don't need authentication.

The [Notification Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Notification+Plugin) is a candidate (if the remote server will install it), but then I have to write an endpoint that can consume its output.  Is there a way I can get my local Jenkins to poll the remote instance?  Other options?

Answer (score 0):

You could get the latest build number from the remote jenkins server at the start of your local job. and then wait X number of minutes and check again until that latest build number changes.

OR, does the remote jenkins have any post build commit steps to a repo you can watch?  If so, you can set up your local job to check the commit repo.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the [Jenkins Remote Access API] to trigger a build?  You can send a json payload (using curl or any other tool of your choice) and this should start a job:

```
    curl -X POST JENKINS_URL/job/JOB_NAME/build \
  --data token=TOKEN \
  --data-urlencode json='{"parameter": [{"name":"id", "value":"123"}, {"name":"verbosity", "value":"high"}]}'
```